# Does google bot crawl comment author link?

Tags: seo, googlebot

I have one interesting question about comment backlink.
As you know, you can leave a comment in wordpress site's post.
Then, you can leave a link to Name field or Comment field as below picture.
[image: comment author link]

When you only leave link in the Name field, Is this link considered as a comment backlink by google bot?
or Should I leave a link in the Comment field?

Answer (score 1):

In general, Google does not count comment backlinks from WordPress. WordPress marks them as `nofollow` links, which [ask Google to not pass link juice](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en).

That said, Google has [recently changed `nofollow` from a directive to merely a "hint"](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/09/evolving-nofollow-new-ways-to-identify.html), so while unlikely, it's not completely impossible that these author links could shape SEO in some way.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. What I want to know is that author link without any link in comment could affect to SEO.

Answer (score 0):

yes google check and this comment link can impact in your seo , you can see after Next term this links added in google.com/webmaster --->links